# PHP Sleep Output before putting to sleep for next step

Tags: php, sleep

I am using `SLEEP()`. It seems the function works, but the script waits until all my `sleep()` functions have ran their course before the script displays any output.

Is there a way I can get output for for 1st and then it should wait and go to next ?

```
    echo date('h:i:s') . "<br />";

    //sleep for 10 seconds
    sleep(10);

    //start again
    echo date('h:i:s'). "<br />";
   //sleep for 10 seconds
    sleep(10);

    //start again
    echo date('h:i:s');
```

I need output of 1st `echo` and then script should wait and give second `echo` ....and so on

Comment: works okay for me, first echo, time, 2nd echo, time, where is the issue?

Comment: @NewBee Yes its working but as i mention its waiting for all sleep before giving all output .

Answer (score 0):

`Sleep` Does not matter as for as output of the page is concerned. Page is served as soon as the last sleep is done... Though it stop processing of the page on server for the time of the sleep. .. in your scenario you should be using javascript for the affect.

Answer (score 0):

You see, PHP runs completely on server-side, and `sleep` will just make the latency of the page more severe.

As Rab has suggested, try using JavaScript instead. It's not the same as Java (in fact, a lot different), and you might like to find some good tutorials online, or get some good books (the one from Murach is really good, trust me).